# NullPointerException when i try to add a object from a jpa repository to a list

Tags: spring-boot, api, jpa, nullpointerexception, spring-repositories

I want to get all projects, where `person` is empty. Every time i call the endpoint a get a `NullPointerException` for this line `emptyProjects.add(project);`. Maybe its because of the `JsonBackReference`?

And if so, is there any way to get the list of projects where the person list is empty?

Project Class:

```
package com.example.api.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectList")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Person> person;

    public Project(){}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(List<Person> person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

Method iam working on:

```
@GetMapping("/project/empty")
    public ResponseEntity getEmptyProjects(){
        List <Project> emptyProjects = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <= projectRepo.findAll().size(); i++){
                Project project = projectRepo.findAll().get(i);
                emptyProjects.add(project);
                if (project.getPerson().isEmpty() == true){
                    emptyProjects.add(project);
                }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(emptyProjects);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing the list, so you're having a NullPointerException because you're trying to call a method on a null object. Replace this line:

```
List <Project> emptyProjects = null;
```

with this

```
List <Project> emptyProjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

Moreover, there is no need of calling the database for each iteration of the loop. It'd be better to save the result in a list `List<Project> allProjects = projectRepo.findAll()` and loop through this list for better performance

Comment: Thanks, for the help. That did the trick. I didn't realized it was, in fact, that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is declared as null means no memory address is assigned for that `emptyProjects`, so when accessing that, you are getting `NPE` error. Moreover, in your loop condition and accessing the elements of `findAll()` resultSet, you are unnecessarily calling that method multiple times which is not ok and your condition checking `for (int i = 0; i <= projectRepo.findAll().size(); i++){` is wrong. check corrected code:

```
@GetMapping("/project/empty")
    public ResponseEntity getEmptyProjects(){
        List <Project> emptyProjects = new ArrayList<>();
        List <Project> resultSet=projectRepo.findAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.size(); i++){
                Project project = resultSet.get(i);
                emptyProjects.add(project);
                if (project.getPerson().isEmpty() == true){
                    emptyProjects.add(project);
                }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(emptyProjects);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Germano Mosconi you will have to initialize **emptyProjects**.

```
  // Fetch all projects
  List<Project> allProjects = projectRepo.findAll();

  // Initialize empty project list here
  List<Project> emptyProjects = new ArrayList<>();

  // Filter projects having empty person.
  for (Project project : allProjects) {
    if (null == project.getPerson()) {
      emptyProjects.add(project);
    }
  }
```